# Table of content like JavaScript-Garden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a table of content similar to [JavaScript Gardens](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/). How do they determine which section is currently active and do you have any recommended JavaScript libraries that imlpement this behavior?

Edit: So the thing I am asking for is how to know which section currently is active on the screen while the user is scrolling so that I can highlight that section in the table of content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect when an element enters the viewport of your browser, and then highlight the corresponding menu entry.

By using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) in Firefox, you can see that they use the `scrollTop` property of the window to know what the user is looking at.

```
highlight: function () {
    // get the scroll height
    var scroll = this.page.window.scrollTop(),
        articleID = this.names[this.names.length - 1].id;
    // while our item are above the viewport, we enumerate
    for (var i = 0, l = this.names.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (this.names[i].offset > scroll) {
            articleID = this.names[i - 1].id;
            break;
        }
    }
    // we've got the content to highlight, let's add classes and expand menu-entries
    var sectionID = articleID.split('.')[0],
        page = this.page,
        nav = page.nav;

    if (sectionID !== page.section) {
        nav.filter('.nav_' + page.section).removeClass('active');
        nav.filter('.nav_' + sectionID).addClass('active');

        this.expand(sectionID);
        page.section = sectionID;
    }

    if (articleID !== page.article) {
        nav.find('a[href="#' + page.article + '"]').removeClass('active');
        nav.find('a[href="#' + articleID + '"]').addClass('active');

        page.article = articleID;
        this.mobile(articleID);
    }
}
```

During the initialization they find out what each part takes in height

```
init: function(attribute) {
 this.heights = this.page.nav.find('ul').map(function(idx, ele) {
 return $(this).outerHeight();
}).get();
```

From these two pieces of info, they can highlight the correct entry to what the user is looking at, by attaching the function to the scroll, resize, etc... events of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via html and css. They use a hover style for each entry and then link to html content via named anchors. You can see that in the address bar when you click on link.

E.g.:

TOC Entry:

```
<a href="#object.hasownproperty" class=""><code>hasOwnProperty</code></a>
```

Content Body:

```
<a name="object.hasownproperty"></a>
<!-- HTML Content here -->
```

Of course, if you want nice animation and stuff, use something like

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/better-html-anchor-a-jquery-script-to-slide-the-scrollbar/ or http://css-plus.com/2011/03/plusanchor-jquery-plugin/

**Update:**

To Achieve highlighting (pseudocode):

1. Keep a tab of all your sections
2. Attach an `onscroll` event handler to the body
3. `onscroll`, check the `scrollTop` to each section's `top`
4. If match found, remove highlight class from previous TOC entry and add it to new TOC entry.

You can name your TOC anchors such a way that they match the section's `id`. Then you can easily retrieve corresponding TOC entry by just saying `#id` and add your class to it.

Comment: Thanks. I clarified my question a bit since I think you misunderstood me.